# Android Studio OutOfMemoryError when trying to get image through Picasso

Tags: android, android-studio, out-of-memory, picasso

EDIT: So apparently the images I'm trying to use are too large. Anyway I can get around this? I'm trying to eventually crop them and set them as my wallpaper programmatically. I've tried a smaller image and it works. Any tips for larger images?

So I'm trying to get an image from a url using Picasso, but when I use the .get() method I'm getting this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:601)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:577)
    at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.decodeStream(BitmapHunter.java:142)
    at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.hunt(BitmapHunter.java:217)
    at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.get(RequestCreator.java:385)
```

I'm executing the Picasso code in AsyncTask because that's where I have some network code fetching the url I need. However, even if I comment out everything and give the url to Picasso directly, the problem persists. With everything commented out my code looks like this:

```
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... name) {
    try {
         return Picasso.with(myContext)
                .load("https://i.redd.it/4l2boppcmn1x.jpg")
                .get();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        android.util.Log.e(TAG, "Failed to retrieve submissions", e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

I've tried everything I could think of including increasing the heap size, adding the largeHeap tag to the manifest, etc. Is this a problem with my code or Android Studio? When using the Memory Monitor while my app is running it says "Free[0.35 MB] Allocated[15.02 MB]" before I even do anything. That can't be right can it? I'm still new to all this so if I am misunderstanding something please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Over 5000x3000 so it need about 60MB... So what's you expected?

Comment: @Selvin Like I said I'm new to this, how can I fix this? I'm wanting to crop it smaller but I can't even load it to do so. Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use resize with Picasso

```
return Picasso.with(myContext)
                .load("https://i.redd.it/4l2boppcmn1x.jpg")
                .resize(500, 300)
                .get();
```

Comment: This fixed my issue with memory but if get my dimensions for my device using DisplayMetrics and resize it that way it only works for some images (I'm also using .centerCrop() after resize). For example if works for the URL in the example but if I try it with this: http://i.imgur.com/AmWThvw.jpg I get OutOfMemoryError. Any tips for handling bigger images?

Comment: Take a look here https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html